# python AssertionError in django

Tags: python, django

I am reading the http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html. I'm new to python and django but have experience with php.

I've come across the following:

```
>>> t = Template("My name is {{ person.first_name }}.")
>>> class PersonClass3:
... def first_name(self):
... raise AssertionError, "foo"
>>> p = PersonClass3()
>>> t.render(Context({"person": p}))
```

this gives the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AssertionError: foo
```

would someone mind explaining why this error occurs? I'm not sure I follow what the problem is. I understand lines 1,2 and 5 but not the others.

Thank you,

Bill

Comment: Probably because you raise an assertion error when that method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has done exactly what the example was trying to show. You “raised” an exception which caused your program to halt execution because there was no handler to deal with it.

[This guide](http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/how-tos/python-exception-handling/index.html) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks Matt, after reading your article I understood what they were getting at in the tutorial. Regards, Bill